# CRTP base class inheriting std::enable_shared_from_this, throwing std::bad_weak_ptr. I need quidance

Tags: c++, c++17

When I try to `share_from_this()` in the base class `shared_handler` to return a `DerivedT` shared pointer, I get an exception thrown: `std::bad_weak_ptr`

I have tried storing an internal shared pointer in the base class, during construction, before ever calling `shared_from_this()`, but I get an even more ambiguous error.

```
template<class DerivedT>
struct shared_handler : std::enable_shared_from_this<DerivedT>
{
  void some_method(arbitrary input) {
    do_something(shared_from_this());
  }
};

struct my_handler : shared_handler<my_handler>
{
  my_handler()
  {
    some_method("hello");
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class DerivedT>
struct shared_handler : std::enable_shared_from_this<shared_handler<DerivedT>>
{
  void some_method(arbitrary input) {
    do_something(shared_from_this());
  }
};
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

> It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Otherwise `std::bad_weak_ptr` is thrown (by the `shared_ptr` constructor from a default-constructed `weak_this`).

Until C++17 it was undefined behavior.

Comment: I now realize this does not fit my use case, and will have to design a custom solution. Thanks for the help.